# Optimize Manufacturing Operations

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

Exercise:

> A company manufactures a good from three productive factors. Your
>   function of production is f (x, y, z) = $-2x^2+y^2-6y-z^2$ , where
>   $x$, $y$ and $z$ represent the number of units used of each factor,
>   respectively. It is requested:
>
> A) Is it possible to produce fixed quantities of $x$, $y$ and $z$ that
>   maximize production?
>
> B) If the cost function of the company is $C (x, y, z) = x + 2y + z$.
>   Study if there are values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ that maximize production
>   for a total cost of 5 units.

I have classified the Hessian and I observed that the point (0,3,0) is a saddle point. I´m blocked and I cant continue.

Comment: So the answer to A is no then? For B you would use the Lagrange multiplier method (it is a constrained optimization problem).

Comment: @Paul  thanks for comment. I have calculated the exercise with restriction and a strict local maximum appears in the point (1,3, -2).